# hashing a file as a Buffer and as a byteArray not producing the same hash (xxHash)

Tags: c#, node.js, hash, buffer

I have a **C# script** that reads a file in byte array and hashes it in 32 bits using [xxhash c#](https://github.com/uranium62/xxHash) algorithm (non-cryptographically hash) like this :

```
 string p = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\bow.png";
 x = hash(File.ReadAllBytes(p), 10);
```

```
  private uint hash(byte[] data , int length, uint seed=0)
        {
           return  xxHash32.ComputeHash(data, length, seed);
        }
```

and i want to produce the same hash in my **expressjs** server using [xxhash JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xxhash) library in js however I don't get the same hash. this is what I'm doing:

```
var XXHash = require('xxhash');
var fs = require('fs');

function getByteArray(filePath){
  let fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString('hex');
  let result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i+=2)
    result.push('0x'+fileData[i]+''+fileData[i+1])
  return result;
}

file = Buffer.from(getByteArray( __dirname + "/Files/nfts/bow.png" ))
const uint32array = new Uint32Array(file);
var result = XXHash.hash(uint32array, 0);
```

I guess the problem is that in the c# script I'm using a **byte array** but in the nodejs I'm using a **buffer**. do you have any idea how to get around that ?

Comment: `hash(File.ReadAllBytes(p), 10)` - why are you hashing only over the first 10 bytes?

Comment: Is key.png and bow.png identical and only have 10 bytes in it?

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks. that was the problem. i just added the length of the array and it worked.

Comment: @Martheen yes they are identical